# Why can't electrons leave the N side and enter the P side in reverse bias?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, reverse-bias

Why can't electrons (excess electrons) of the N side of a semiconductor diode enter the P side via the battery in reverse bias mode of PN junction? like this:[image]

Comment: PN junction: What does a battery have to do with that?!

Comment: Did Do you mean why can't the battery swap its polarity to be forward-biased in respect to the PN junction?

Comment: They do, to a small extent. Then the growing depletion region produces enough of an electric field to balance it out, and the conduction stops. (except for a small leakage current)

Comment: The electric field of depeletion layer (its direction of action should promote e- movemnt to the right)

Comment: https://gfycat.com/menacingfixedamericancrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With battery positive on N and battery negative on P you have a reverse biased PN junction. That forms a wide depletion layer that is basically non conductive unless the breakdown voltage is exceeded.

The majority carrier electrons in the N material are attracted to the battery positive terminal but, there is only a limited supply of them and this produces a really tiny glitch of charge movement into the battery that is unsustainable.

It's a similar story for the majority carriers in the P material: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/semiconductor_devices/semiconductor_devices_junction_diodes.htm).

Comment: So Do all the charges in the N material fade away after biasing

Comment: As limited charges get used up right

Comment: They redistribute towards battery positive and stop moving. That means they stop flowing and current rapidly becomes zero amps.

Comment: Ow so thats why  the cause of current through the semi conductor diode is drifting of charges mainly right(after breakdown)?

Comment: Drift current i mean to say

Comment: clarify your point please.

Comment: After breakdown voltage is achieved ,in the depletion region Electrons get stripped off of their bonds right? and create electron hole pair generation which is the cause of current after breakdown voltage right

Comment: Is this the valid reason? because i read from a source that this is why conduction increases after breakdown is that correct?

Comment: Yup its on the internet thankyou so much

Comment: It's correct @Damstridium

Comment: Thankyou so much

Answer (score 3):

They can, if you apply a high enough voltage. We call that "breakdown". Normally the electrons do not have enough energy to cross the depletion region.

Comment: No I mean There are exess electrons on the n side right? So if we apply reverse biasing ie connect the positive terminal of the battery with diode then why cant electrons just go through the battery and reach the holes on other side? why go through the pain of going in depletion region.I mean the electric field will of the battery will make them move towards positive terminal

Comment: Go through the battery? In which direction? _Add a diagram_

Comment: I have added it

Comment: I know this can look stupid but i am new to semi conductors so sorry if you feel the frustration

Comment: Break the silence bro i am sorry i know but i had to just ask this

Comment: Why don't the electrons just flow backward through the battery?  Because -- battery?